# Improvements to a Size and Strength Meal Plan

Tags: diet, nutrition

23 year old male, 84kg, 20% B.F. Currently training for size and strength.

I've linked my proposed training and rest day meal plans [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YEHqApLZMIA66TgFmEFAKh2wBwFmQgROMLzem66vKIc/edit?usp=sharing)

All the weights I worked out myself and inputted everything into [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com) (MFP) to yield the pie charts at the bottom.

For lack of a better work I am a bit 'worried' about my macros; I think I'm straying a bit from the 50% carb, 25% fat and 25% protein ratio. Saying this, I'm not entirely sure how accurate MFP actually is/how truly representative it is - my diet consists of a lot of 'good' fats and the only sources of saturated fats I can pick out are from the milk and butter and I'm loading up on fruit and veg on both days.

So from a no-numbers standpoint, how does my diet look? I don't think I should be massively anal about the numbers because different sources quote different numbers so I have no idea which to take as gospel.

In terms of improvements, I've been advised to try and up my protein intake to 2g/kg of bodyweight and trim down on the carbs on rest days but I'm struggling a bit as to which foods I should add/replace - any recommendations?

Comment: It would be nice if you could summarize the information in the link, otherwise future answers will be somewhat irrelevant once the spreadsheet changes/goes away.

Comment: Quite a lot to summarise. The answer I'm looking for is very much dependent on looking at it anyway. I don't intend to change it, only edit and add an updated version once I've received some feedback.

Comment: Personally, I'd replace your grains on your non-training day with eggs (so replace the pasta and quinoa with eggs. Quick and easy sources of dietary fat and protein. 50% daily energy from carbs is also relatively high (so is 41% for a rest day since you seem to be cal / carb cycling).